# Formatting month and day depending on the user culture

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to find a clean way to format a DateTime to show the day and month depending on the user culture.
My expected result:
en-US: MM/dd -> 11/19
de-DE: dd.MM -> 19.11

Here is my current solution with works... but is there a better way to do this?

```
var d = DateTime.Now;
var dateFormatter = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;
return d.ToString(dateFormatter.ShortDatePattern
    .Replace("y", "")
    .Trim(dateFormatter.DateSeparator.ToCharArray()));
```

Comment: How do you know user's culture? No browser sends this information to server, you have to pass Date as milliseconds since EPOCH and then use browser to display a localized date.

Comment: Not sure how you claim _"my current solution works"_. All it does is format the date based on the culture of the server, not the client.

Answer (score 0):

To format a Datetime depend on the specific culture, you can set the current culture:
`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");`

You can get more information and see the sample in this link:
 [enter link description here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, it can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: thanks for your comment. Sorry because i'm a new member

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this to force Spanish:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo esES = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES");
Convert.ToDateTime(filtroIU.fechaIngresoInicio, esES);
```

Just take the current culture and it should work.

```
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
```